# Does hitting bells in the Clock Tower do anything?

Tags: dead-cells

In the Clock Tower there are bells I can hit to make a ringing noise and a a visible wave. It doesn't seem to have any effect on enemies. Is there any purpose to hitting these bells?

[image: Hitting a bell]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a puzzle here involving the four background bells.
To solve this puzzle, the four bells must be rang in a *specific order*

> from the lowest pitch to the highest.

Solving the puzzle grants

> the **Bell Tower Key** to the door leading to the blueprint for **Punishment**.

Source, [Dead Cells wiki](https://deadcells.fandom.com/wiki/Clock_Tower#Bell_puzzle).